# Algorithm to map out a closed maze and remember how it looks for future use

Tags: mapping, maze, agent

I'm working on a project where I'll have an agent in a random maze, and this maze does not have an exit. The goal would be for the agent to explore the maze and 'remember' how it looks. After some time I'll spawn an item at a random location and the agent will be notified only if it has mapped out that given area. The agent will use the map it has generated to determine the shortest path to the item.

I know of maze algorithms like A*, but these algorithms require a start and end position for the traversal to stop. These algorithms don't 'remember' how the maze looks they just determine the shortest path between two points. Since the maze is closed there is no end position. My initial idea was to have the agent travel randomly and fill in a 2D array of how the map looks, this just seems inefficient to me. Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

So you will have two steps, exploration and traversing.

Suppose you have explored the maze completely, then when the item appears, you can just use A* with goal being the item.

To explore the map and store it, you can create a data structure appropriate for the map. For example, if the connecting paths don't matter and only the conjunctions do, then just create a Node class where each node has a list of connected nodes. Finally, you can start a breadth-first search or depth-first search to explore the whole map, while storing the info in the aforementioned data structure.

Depending on the actual map, either exploration algorithms might be more effective. I'd start with depth-first though, since that sounds similar to our human approach to mazes - always turn in the same direction at an intersection! (Good that dfs takes care of circular paths!)